# How to add metadata to images that easily appear in Windows 10 with matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, metadata

I am trying to add metadata to images saved from graphs in matplotlib using:

```
plt.savefig("image1.jpeg", metadata = {"Camera maker": "XYZ"}
```

However, none of that info appears while inspecting the image's properties in Windows 10. I know the metadata I specified in the plt.savefig() exists (I checked it with additional software), but I want to be able to have a metadata that displays in Windows 10 just by letting the cursor on the image.

Comment: Isn't that a windows problem? Does it actually show the `Camera maker` field for any file?

Comment: Are you saving to a jpg or a png.  Your question is tagged with png but your example shows jpg.  If a png then don't expect Windows to display anything. Windows metadata support in png files is close to non-existent.

Comment: @StarGeek, yes, you are right. I first did it in PNG, but later noticed that JPEG was the way to go (at least the one that *might* work)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest With JPEG files it does. In File Properties, many fields (even Lenses) appear there with info depending of the device used to take the photo.

Comment: I see. So I cannot find the metadata in the jpeg file (which contradicts *"I know the metadata I specified in the plt.savefig() exists"*), only in the png file. This would makes sense in thus far as matplotlib itself saves png files, but for saving jpg files it falls back to PILLOW and probably does not forward the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try manually adding camera data to a file using the windows 10 interface. Use a tiff file to do this (You'd be surprised how similar the metadata works between tiff and png these days). 
Once you do this, use whatever tool you have to read the camera maker data from that tiff file. That will let you know what keys windows actually saves that information to. 
Then just use that same behavior in your code, and it should work.

I've only done this with py3exiv2 in windows 7, but this strategy should get you moving if you're stuck.

Comment: Hello Fergus. I did this and it did not work. The metadata keys were the same that appeared with other image formats, but still they do not appear when I add them with Matplotlib

Comment: Dang. I'm not familiar with Matplotlib or any limitations it my have in manipulating exif data. That's weird it wouldn't throw an error if you tried but failed to manipulate the value of a specific key. It is possible that the value was changed, and Matplotlib can read the file again to confirm that change, but for some reason windows 10 just doesn't show you.

Answer (score 1):

The [`savefig` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) states:

> `metadata` : dict, optional
>
> Key/value pairs to store in the image metadata. The supported keys and defaults depend on the image format and backend:
>
> - 'png' with Agg backend: See the parameter metadata of [`print_png`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.print_png).
> - 'pdf' with pdf backend: See the parameter metadata of [`PdfPages`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages).
> - 'eps' and 'ps' with PS backend: Only 'Creator' is supported.

This means **the `metadata` argument is ignored for jpg images**.

In case of jpg images you would need to use the `pil_kwargs` argument instead. Valid PIL/pillow arguments are in [the Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg) and one of them is `"exif"`. It would expect the exif as raw bytes.
Therefore one can use a package like [`piexif`](https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html) to povide the data.

It could look like this:

```
import piexif
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


exif_dict = {"0th" : {piexif.ImageIFD.Make: u"Canon",}}
exif_byte = piexif.dump(exif_dict)

plt.savefig("image1.jpg", pil_kwargs = {"exif" : exif_byte} )

plt.show()
```

This will save the exif information into the file. Windows may or may not recognize it; so that is a totally different topic.

Comment: Hello, I followed your code above, but then no exif appeared when checking my new jpeg with various tools. I read the documentation, tried different keys, but none of that worked.

Comment: I did check this with `exiftool` ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUyQ.png)) as well as with Irfanview ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOQkj.png)) and it works fine.